# Google auth logout issue in angular 2

Tags: angular

Iam new to angular js. Iam working on an angular project with version 2.
I have implemented google auth login using angular2-social-login by following https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-social-login.
Google sign in is working correctly, but after logout when i click on the login button iam still getting the previously logged in user details and google auth login page is not showing.
Here is details of my implementation.

Installation
via npm

```
npm install angular2-social-login --save
```

Adding angular2-social-login to your project
Add map for angular2-social-login in your systemjs.config

```
'angular2-social-login': 'node_modules/angular2-social-login/dist/bundles/angular2-social-login.min.js'
```

Main module configuration

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Angular2SocialLoginModule } from "angular2-social-login";

let providers = {
    "google": {
      "clientId": "GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"
    },
    "linkedin": {
      "clientId": "LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID"
    },
    "facebook": {
      "clientId": "FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID",
      "apiVersion": "<version>" //like v2.4 
    }
  };

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
              BrowserModule,
              Angular2SocialLoginModule
          ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { 
  constructor(){}
}
Angular2SocialLoginModule.loadProvidersScripts(providers);
```

Component configuration for login() and logout():
For login(provider: string) provider is required it should be anyone(case-sensitive) "facebook", "google", "linkedin" .

```
...
import { AuthService } from "angular2-social-login";
...
@Component({
    ...
})
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
  ...
  constructor(public _auth: AuthService){ }

  signIn(provider){
    this.sub = this._auth.login(provider).subscribe(
      (data) => {
                  console.log(data);
                  //user data 
                  //name, image, uid, provider, uid, email, token (accessToken for Facebook & google, no token for linkedIn), idToken(only for google) 
                }
    )
  }

  logout(){
    this._auth.logout().subscribe(
      (data)=>{//return a boolean value.} 
    )
  }

  ...

}
```

Advance thanks.

Comment: do a `unsubscribe` after finishing login

Comment: can you please clarify

Comment: this.sub.unsubscribe as it gets a observable

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working for me.

Comment: Try this example code - https://github.com/abacritt/angular4-social-login/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Where is stored data of logged in user? May these data wasn't cleared?

Comment: After logout from google iam not able to login with another user using google auth.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Angular 6 and here is my code for logging out google account:

In my TS file, declare a variable auth2, a variable gapi, and a function googleLogout:

```
declare const gapi: any;//this line should be at the very top of your TS file
public auth2: any;
 public googleLogout() {
    gapi.load('auth2', () => {
      this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
      this.auth2.signOut().then(function() {
        console.log("User signed out");
      });
      //this.attachSignout(document.getElementById('googleBtn2'));
    });
  }
```

Then, in the html file, give an element and bind with a click function:

```
<div id="googleBtn2" (click)="googleLogout()">Google SignOut</div>
```

Don't forget to include the google api in the index.html:

```
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```